# How to read a file from WEB-INF/resources folder?

Tags: jasper-reports, icefaces

I am using Icefaces for webapplication development. I wish to read a file from the resources folder and use it in the sessionbean.

Actually I wish to setup Jasper Reports. I have already setup the libraries in the classpath. The problem I get is while fetching the file from /WEB-INF/resources/ folder. Everytime I run the code from SessionBean, I get the exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /resources/reports/myreport.jrxml (No such file or directory)
```

The Code I use is:

```
public void generateReport() {
    try {
            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(
                    "/resources/reports/myreport.jrxml",
                    "/resources/reports/myreport.jasper");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The above code is in the SessionBean.
Plz help

Comment: Why is it down voted? Is it because you do not know the answer? I don't think this question is off-topic..

Comment: People don't downvote because they don't know the answer, they downvote because they don't think the question is a good match for SO. Unfortunately they don't always leave a reason. Personally, I think if you look at the API doc and see that it takes a filename, and your code, which clearly passes in an absolute path, it's obvious what the problem is, although I wouldn't downvote just for that.

Comment: Sorry about that... I was simply seeking an answer as I searched at many places and didn't get any working answer.

Comment: No apologies necessary, just saying why some ppl might downvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing relative
URLs to method `JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile`.
This method expects filenames as parameters, not URLs.

The solution suggested in other internet forums is:

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(
  getServletContext().getRealPath(xmlFile), 
  getServletContext().getRealPath(compiledFile));
```

Comment: That is my problem.. What is the workaround to specify the file which exists in the /WEB-INF/resources/ folder?

Comment: Thanks for the response. But its not working - the 'getservletcontext()' part. I am not able to get the servlet context in a com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractSessionBean. Also I am using Visual Icefaces for development.. Plz can u help? Any workaround?

Comment: You have to find the method calls to access the servlet request.  It will be something like
`((HttpSession)AbstractSessionBean.getExternalContext().getSession(false)).getServletContext()`

Comment: Though I had to workaround for 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester.SetNestedPropertiesRule. 
Otherwise the file was found successfully...